# Sending input from HTML using callback

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I have the code for the input from a user, and I have the callback, I am just confused on how to have the data sent using the callback

my code:

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<base target="\_top">

</head>

<body>

<label>User info: </label>

<div align="justify">

<input type= "text" id = "email">

</div>

<br>

<button id="searchData"> Search data sheet </button>

<script> 
//Above creates a box for user input [//document.getElementById](//document.getElementById)("searchData").addEventListener("click",addHeaders); document.getElementById("searchData").addEventListener("click",google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).testCase()); 
//gets the button1 element and listens for a click then runs the function addName. 
function onSuccess(numUnread) { 
var div = document.getElementById('output'); 
div.innerHTML = numUnread 
} &#x200B; 
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).testCase() 
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Apps Script

```js
function doGet() {

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('frontEnd');

}

function testCase(input)

{

  Logger.log((input + ' hello'))

  return (input + ' hello')

}
```

My expected would be the input + " hello", instead I got "undefined hello"

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that in your html you have a button like this with a div above it:

```
<body>
<div id="message"></div>
<input type="button" value="Hello" onClick="sayHello();" />

<script>
  //When you click the button this function gets called
  function sayHello() {
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(msg){
       document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=msg;//message will appear in the div
     })
    .sayHelloToServer();//This function is on the server
    console.log('My Code');
</script>
</body>
```

Then in Code.gs:

```
function sayHelloToServer() {
  return "Hello.  We're very happy that you came to visit us.";//this is returned to withSuccessHandler(function(msg){}) or you can also use a standalone function in which you simply put its name in like this .withSuccessHandler(funcname)
}
```

This is explained in [Client to Server Communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)